# How to remove the visualization of a triangular mesh on objects and make a realistic rendering of objects?

Tags: drake, sdf, meshcat

I trid to get realistic visualization of objects in Meshcat: I export 3d model from CAD-model to .obj with .mtl files by using MeshLab program. And when I set .obj file in .sdf  I get like this in meshcat with visualization of triangles and not with clear boundaries:

[image: Visualization in Meshcat]

But in MeshLab model in .obj+.mtl seems like this:
[image: Model in MeshLab]

And in CAD-system my model semms like this:
[image: Model in CAD-system]

1. How to get a more realistic rendering of a model in a meshcat without visualization triangles on the surface?
2. In documentation I found commands **SetTriangleMesh()** and **SetTriangleColorMesh()**, but I'm not sure if this is what I need. Are there any examples of using these commands?
3. I found a [very realistic representation](https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/42557859/290610824-6af8ea48-f666-4582-b31d-5b89dc5a9eb6.gif?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.z8Rkds638oWasmBy4XVs5F8hW1HS--hWCtFA4JFwvyk) of a dish drainer [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/19142) but how does it works?

To model contact I'm using a simplified model and question only about visualization of models.

**Edited**
[OBJ file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mhMisWyu5W5nTezvTP-7aXF-pkW6tKD1/view?usp=drive_link)
[MTL file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xgkvB47yU3nUOBfXfCAf6jBeyyfPywNi/view?usp=drive_link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your obj file and answer the following questions:

1. Do you have lines that start with `vn`?
2. On the lines that start with `f` do they have lines like `f 1 2 3` or `f 1//1 2//2 3//3` (the actual integer values are unimportant. The [question of whether there are slashes or not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Vertex_normal_indices_without_texture_coordinate_indices) is what is important).

The hypothesis we're targeting is that your obj has not explicitly defined its surface normals, so each visualizer (meshcat vs meshlab) is applying its default logic. Making sure that your obj has explicit normals is the first step to guaranteeing a uniform appearance.

Comment: 1. I have lines that start with **vn**: **...
vn -4.739915 -4.075434 0.132349
v -0.005728 0.085778 -0.036000
vn -0.110599 -4.315876 -0.002976
v -0.003182 0.083232 -0.036000
...**
2.  In .obj file after **v and vn-lines** there are lines with a slash:
** usemtl material_0
f 2//2 5//5 1//1
f 3//3 2//2 1//1
f 5//5 6//6 1//1
...
**

After  **v and vn-lines** I have  _# 196757 vertices, 0 vertices normals_.
After  **f-lines** I have _# 379038 faces, 0 coords texture_.

I added a file to the main body of the question.

Comment: What do you think? Which tool (or program) are you using to convert 3D-cad model to .obj for visualization in Drake?

Comment: So, it seems the vast majority of your faces don't have specified normals. I don't routinely process cad models, but if I had your objs, I'd run to blender to add normals.

Comment: It helped me, thank you! 
I found conversion method to get good models for visualization: First, convert model in CAD-program to STEP 2014, then convert step 2014 to .obj in CAD-Assistant program and in the end convert .obj from cad-assistant to .obj in Blender. If anyone points out an easier way in the future, please comment here!